# Question about parallel displacement on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is Problem 9.6(1) from the book [The Geometry of Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602602):

> What's wrong with the following argument?
>
> A vector $\mathbf v$ is parallel displaced around a small closed curve $C = \partial{U^2}$ in an $n$-dimensional manifold $M^n$. Then $dv^i = -\omega^i_jv^j$ along $C$. Thus the total change in $v^i$ on going around $C$ is given by
>
> $$\begin{align}\Delta v^i &= \oint_{C}\,dv^i = -\oint\omega^i_jv^j\\ &= -\iint_U\,d(\omega^i_jv^j)\\&= -\iint_U\,d(\omega^i_j)v^j-\omega^i_j\wedge dv^j \\&= -\iint_U [d\omega^i_k + \omega^i_j\wedge\omega^j_k]v^k\\&=-\iint_U\theta^i_kv^k\\&=-\iint_U\frac{1}{2}R^i_{krs}v^k\,dx^r\wedge dx^s\end{align}$$

where $\omega$ is the connection, $\theta$ is the curvature $2$-form. I think this should be independent of $v$, but I am not sure where it is wrong.

Comment: I haven't carefully checked the calculation, but wouldn't one expect the change in $v$ to depend on $v$? (The _endomorphism of the tangent space_ doesn't depend on $v$, of course, but that looks consistent with your last line.)

Comment: @user86418 It should be equal to $\iint K\,ds$, where $K$ is the gaussian curvature.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve $c$ is a boundary curve and if $\{e_i\}$ is a moving along $c$ and $\omega_i$ is a coframe then we have a connection $$ 
\omega_{is} (X):=\omega_i (\nabla_X e_s)$$ And $$ v:=v^i e_i,\ \nabla_{c'(t)} v =0 $$

Hence if $c'(t)=Y^ie_i$ then $$ Y(v^i) + v^s \omega_{is} (Y) =0$$

That is $$ \int dv^i =\int -v^s\omega_{is} $$

So $v$ is dependent.

Comment: Now I understand it is $v$ dependent, but is the above calculation quoted from the book right? The problem asks to find the fault of the calculation.

Comment: from the book ? I am quoted from a book which is not indicated by you. And I do not read the book. And i think that there exists no fault (I write $\omega_i$ which is corresponded to $dx_i$. General $dx_i$ is denoted as a coordinate $1$-form. So usually, we write $\omega_1$.)

Comment: But I think that the notation in OP is fine and there is no big problem. And if you have a something in calculation, then please you point concretely.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood, I am asking whether the calculation in my question (which is quoted from a problem in the book I mentioned) is right or not, and presumably it is not right because the author explicitly said ‘what's wrong with the following argument’.

Comment: I see. Consider Stokes Thm : For instance $$ \alpha = ydx-xdy,\ \int_C \alpha =\int\int_D d\alpha $$ Here if we use the $\alpha$ then we can calculate the area of $D$. Here note that $\alpha$ is define on $D$. In OP, $\alpha=\omega^i_j v^j$ is not defined on $U$.

Comment: Simply how can we define $v$ on the boundary. For general manifold, let $c : [0,1]\rightarrow  \partial U$ with $c(0)=c(1)=p$. Then $ v(0)=v(1)$ is not right for general case. If we consider $S^2(1)$, then we realize it.